# Select text without sibling markup

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want to select with XPath only the value from span class="value" without the currency sign character.

```
<span class="infoValue">
<span class="value">
<span class="currencyLeft">$</span>
1000
</span>
</span>

//span[@class='infoValue']//span[@class='value']
```

With this xpath, I can select "$1000" . How can I remove or get only the "1000" without " $ " sign  with XPath?

When I try with this.

```
//span[@class='infoValue']//span[@class='value']/span[not(currencyLeft)]"
```

I only get again the currency sign "$".

Answer (score 1):

There are `<span>` nodes and text nodes. If you select a span node, you always get the $, because every span node contains it and XPath only selects complete nodes with all their descendants. But $ and 1000 are text nodes, so you can choose one of them:

```
//span[@class='infoValue']/span[@class='value']/text()
```

Alternatively, you can treat the span as string and remove the string `"$"`  (`"$"` is a $, not the `$` in the XML file, since latter $ is associated with a certain position/parent/... in the XML file). Although this only works for a single value:

```
normalize-space(translate(//span[@class='infoValue']/span[@class='value'], "$", ""))
```

Comment: This will pick up undesired whitespace, which will be difficult to trim with `normalize-space()` because there may be multiple text nodes returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
'normalize-space(//span[@class="value"]/text()[normalize-space()])'
```

Comment: This works (+1).  Might want to wrap with another `normalize-space()` in order to remove any leading or trailing whitespace surrounding the `1000`.

Comment: Thanks to all.
$x("normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'balanceBox')]//span[@class='infoValue']//span[@class='value']/text())")
result - "2.000,00" - but when I use this xpath in my code, i got always Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <org.openqa.selenium.remote

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//span[@class='currencyLeft']/following-sibling::text())
```

will select

```
1000
```

as requested.

You can, of course, specify the heritage to `/span[@class='currencyLeft']` more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
substring-after(//span[@class="value"], "$")
```

use `substring-after` function:

> Returns the substring of the first argument string that follows the
>   first occurrence of the second argument string in the first argument
>   string, or the empty string if the first argument string does not
>   contain the second argument string.